# Docker error with mysql connexion when docker-up

Tags: php, mysql, docker, symfony

I have a problem with docker and mysql (i am pretty new with docker)
I am trying to use symfony 3.4 with docker.

I have this error :

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 103:
>
> An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddre
>     sses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 47:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name d
>     oes not resolve
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 43:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name d
>     oes not resolve
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 43:
>
> PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does
>      not resolve

And i really don't know what to do ...

Here is my docker-compose :

```
version: "3"

services:
  apache:
    build: ./docker/apache/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - php
  php:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8000"
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.0
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /docker/database:/etc/mysql/conf.d
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=toor
      - MYSQL_USER=me
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pwd
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=name
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=db
      - PMA_PORT=3306
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - db
```

My docker file :

```
FROM php:7.3-rc-zts-alpine

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | \
php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer install

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080 8000

CMD ["php",  "bin/console", "server:run", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

And my config for symfony :

```
parameters:
   database_host: db
   database_port: 3306
   ...
```

Comment: Not sure but in your docker-compose, your php container doesn't have a link to the db container (have a look at the phpmyadmin which has `links:... - db`.

Comment: links is obsoleted ( https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links )

Comment: yes .... even with link is not working (i also tried in php to do a depends_on : db)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve" suggests that the dns name for the database server failed.

I am not sure what you are using for your database_host, but it looks like you are assuming your symfony config is going to resolve the location of "db" from the docker compose process.  This is not the case.  You need to create your symfony config database host based on the ip address running the database container.  When you add container orchestration to the mix, things will start getting even more complicated.  You should look into some form of service discovery to help manage this problem.

Comment: in my symfony parameter i tried to put 127.0.0.1 and still don't work ... I tried a connection with mysqlworkbench and it works ! ... But when i put same parameters to my symfony parameter it don't work ... ?

Comment: PhpMyAdmin `links:` to the DB but apache and php do not.

Answer (score 1):

When you run docker-compose up , all containers will start , the issue you have is that your php container start too quickly .

And after , the database server will take a long time to start 1 sec or more.

You php is not patient , and does not retry .

You must do a loop to check if you db is up , in my example i use 
  `nc -z db 3306` to see if i connect to the port 3306 of the host `db`

A example of a setup with a Docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  php:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8000"
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.0
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=toor
      - MYSQL_USER=me
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pwd
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=name
```

and a docker file

```
FROM php:7.3-rc-zts-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add netcat-openbsd && apk add mariadb-client

CMD ["/bin/sh","-c", \
     "( while ( ! nc -z db 3306 >/dev/null 2>&1 ) ; do \
           date ; sleep 4 ; \
        done ;  \
        mysql -h db -u me -ppwd name -e \"show databases\"; sleep 3600 ; ) " ]
```